# Aplicación en react-nextjs cuando recargo una página esta se rompe, sale error 404

Tags: reactjs, nextjs

Estamos creando una landing page, con nextjs vr:10.0.9 y react vr: 17.0.1. tengo mis rutas tal cual especifican en la documentación oficial de nextjs https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link, el problema es cuando recargo una pagina cual quiera, me sale este error, de momento para evitar eso estamos redirigiendo a la pagina del home. no estamos consumiendo ninguna api por ahora.

Ya hemos intentado con otras herramientas de ruteo, revisado configuración, configuración de **`next.config`** y hasta el momento ninguna a funcionado. El mismo problema resulta tanto en el entorno de prueba como en el de producción.

Adjunto capturas del problema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acudo a uds. comunidad para que por favor nos ayuden a encontrar la solución.

Adjunto código de lo que estamos haciendo

```
  const itemsMenu = [
    { name: Lang.labelHowItWorks, ref: "/howItWorks" },
    { name: Lang.labelTestimonials, ref: "/Testimonials" },
    { name: Lang.labelAboutUs, ref: "/aboutUs" },
    { name: Lang.labelContactUs, ref: "/ContactUs" },
  ];
```

---

```
    <Link key={LinkIndex} href={item.ref}>
                  <a
                    className="flex flex-col mt-2 mx-14 hover:text-gray-800 font-semibold text-gray-400"
                    onClick={onClose}
                  >
                    {item.name}
                  </a>
                </Link>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que hace la función `onClose` que está dentro del método `onClick`? Y otra cosa, ¿seguro que todos los nombres de las rutas son exactamente iguales a los nombres de tus archivos que están guardados en la carpeta `pages` de tu proyecto?

Comment: que mas bro te comparto la respuesta.                                          
    ``` const [active, setActive] = useState(false);

  const handleOpen = () => {
    setActive(true);
  };

  const onClose = () => {
    setActive(false);
  };     ```                                                                                                      y si los nombres de las rutas son iguales a los archivos. :/

Answer (score 0):

Prueba usando un archivo .htaccess, por ejemplo para un dominio xyz.com donde se creo un portal con nextjs puedes usar este archivo:

```
  RewriteEngine On  
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```